# How to get value from ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have created a JRadioButton Group, and I want to set a parameter to a value when a specific button is selected. I have added ActionListener to this button like the codes. But I how can I use the value in other actionlisteners?

```
grid_rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
network_type = "--grid-net";
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a getter and setter:

```
String networkType;

grid_rb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        setNetworkType("--grid-net");
    }
});

public void getNetworkType() {
    return networkType;
}
public void setNetworkType(String nwt) {
    networkType = nwt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons have a method `isSelected()`, that tells you if the button is selected or not.